# Retrieve data with a range from a different Spreadsheet than the one I'm currently working on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to get data by specifying a range from antother Spreadsheet and when found, set the value in specific range in my current spreadsheet.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("My link ID");

var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Overview'); 
var range = sheet.getSheetValues(4,2,14,1);

var thedata = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B3').setValue(range);
```

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code I'm currently using. For some reason I'm not getting all the data range I'm trying to retrieve, just the first row

Comment: @DavidSalomon I would appreciate your feedback

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Not at all. Just getting the first cell of data and not the entire range

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 options:

### 1. [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

You can use this function to retrieve info from another spreadsheet

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")
```

### 2. [Get Spreadsheet by ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))

Opens the spreadsheet with the given ID. A spreadsheet ID can be extracted from its URL.

```
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
    Logger.log(ss.getName());
```